# Giant battery consumption with dual graphics solution (only i-gpu working)

Tags: intel-graphics, battery, nvidia-optimus

I use a Laptop with Intel Core i7 SandyBridge and integrated Intel HD3000 graphics as well as a Nvidia Geforce GTS 555M. So far, I got the impression my Laptop was running with the Nvidia graphics adapter only because the fan was always running on highest speed (and loudest noise) and it was getting very hot even when doing nothing. Also the battery is empty after ~40-50 minutes (while having ~4-5 hours with Intel graphics in Win7). Since this can't be healthy I wanted to switch to the integrated graphics instead.
I was fairly surprised when the System Information showed me that the as graphics adapter I use "Intel M". Why is my battery empty so fast with Ubuntu? Without using the NVIDIA graphics adapter?

Summary:
I DONT WANT to use the Nvidia graphics adapter (OPTIMUS), I just want the Intel solution. As I have understood, the Intel solution is running already, emptying my battery 10x as fast as Win7. What is wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu turns on Nvidia by default, despite it showing as Intel M, so your best bet is to try switchable graphics (at your own risk though).

Using [Ironhide](https://launchpad.net/~mj-casalogic/+archive/ironhide), you can manually switch to using Intel graphics.

Also note that there is a current regression in Ubuntu Oneiric which causes upto 30% more power consumption on Sandy Bridge laptops (acknowledged in Ubuntu Release notes).

update: Canonical is testing Oneiric (and Precise) Kernel's with the Matthew Garrett ASPM patches which brings down the battery consumption to Maverick level's test it over [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement)

Comment: So the only way of getting more battery life in Ubuntu is waiting for Precise Pangolin? Besides that I'll try my luck with ironhide.